# Ignore UnicodeDecodeError for older pandas version

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a very specific problem. I am handling very big csv, files and they are not perfect all the time. Even though the files is in fact encoded with "utf-8", there are wrong bytes in it that cant be decoded.  These bytes throw a UnicodeDecodeError:
`'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 427: character maps to <undefined>`

What i want to do is just ignore and replace the bytes that cant be decoded.I know that pandas 1.3 has a feature to ignore decoding errors, but i am on an older Version of pandas and cant update in the near future.
Is there a other way to achieve the same result in older pandas versions?

Comment: Which version of pandas you are using?

Comment: 0.23.3, but i could go up to 1.1

Comment: That's a strange error from UTF-8 decoding, where 9e would be the first byte of a multi-byte sequence. It is much more likely to come from trying to interpret some UTF-8 data as iso-8859-x, where 9e is indeed in an undefined range. Are you sure that you are trying to read the data as UTF-8?

Comment: You are right i posted the wrong Error, when i was testing with different encodings.
```"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 2: invalid start byte"```
is the error i get with utf-8

Comment: Very likely, the problem is that your encoding is wrong in the first place.

Comment: That might be the case i need to guess the encoding because i dont get the encoding from the file provider, but every encoding guessing method i found is not 100% accurate, so i need a way to ignore charmap errors and drop the errors. Sure i could just use Latin1 or something, but then the whole text would be mostly unreadable.